# A non jew put a mezuzah back up, now what

Tags: halacha, mezuzah

If a mezzuzah fell and a non Jewish employee put it back up

Theoretically is there an obligation to take it down and put it up by a Jew? (With a bracha?)

Or is it kosher the way it is?

Comment: a couple of questions. Did the ink or the scroll get damaged. Does anybody live at the place of business, like sleep there overnight, I mean a jew of course. The answer to these questions may help to answer your original question properly.

Comment: @gamliela no usually no one sleeps, no evidence of ink damage

Comment: @DoubleAA How is this higher-quality question from 2017 a dupe of the practical-psak-seeking question from yesterday?

Answer (score 1):

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BafNIu_hXrw) (after 1'30") reports a similar question was asked to R Yosef Shalom Eliashiv who brought a Maharam Shick that it was allowed for a non-Jew to put up a mezuza if a person is old/sick and can't do it himself. He argues the *mitzva* is to have a mezuza not to put it on.

However, others (the Sdei Chemed, R Shmuel Wosner) argue that putting up the mezuza has to be *lishma*, for its own sake, which only a Jew can do.

Since it is a dispute, R Eliashiv ruled that, for the sake of resolving the doubt, it was better for a Jew to rehang the mezuza (e.g., removing a nail then setting it back).

As always, be sure to ask a rabbi in any specific case.